# Server-side time countdown. Perform an action on a record in the database after countdown passes

Tags: php, laravel

I have never worked with time functions in Laravel. I send a post from android to my Laravel REST API, where I include a certain time, for e.g 30 seconds. In 30 seconds I must change a column of this post in the database. What is the best way to perform this action? What if I have 100 simultaneous records in the database that must be checked? I was thinking about async functions. What would be the best and fastest solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always use SQL event.

```
DB::statement('CREATE EVENT Expiration ON SCHEDULE AT FROM_UNIXTIME(?) DO BEGIN /**your code**/, [$somedate]);
```

Comment: can I use this query to change a column value in x seconds? Thank you!

Comment: Of course, just include `use Carbon\Carbon;` in your controller and do `DB::statement('CREATE EVENT Expiration ON SCHEDULE AT FROM_UNIXTIME(?) DO BEGIN /**your code**/, [Carbon::Now()->addSeconds(30)]);`

Comment: thank you very much! can you provide a link with a demo or documentation to this?

Comment: Sure, look [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html) for some information about SQL Events and [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/database) for DB queries in Laravel. There's no example of this in the Laravel documentation, but I've tried this personally in one of my project and it worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

you can use laravel worker and dispatch your work with 30 second delay ... but you should know that, this solution is not really accurate and may your work really not start in 30 second (maybe 35 second on many work together) ...

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues